# Segfault on `mkl_malloc`

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, valgrind, intel-mkl

## Context

I want to use Intel's MKL library to create an array and then do various stuff with it. However, it segfaults on `mkl_malloc`.

## Problem

I am trying to run the following program. On running it, I get a segfault at the specified line. The problem is with `mkl_malloc`. What can I do to fix this? What is going on?

```
#include "mkl_types.h"
#include "mkl_spblas.h"
#include <stddef.h>  // For NULL
#include <stdio.h>


// Find reason for segfault
int main() {
    MKL_INT m=2000, k=1000;
    double  *A_dense;

    // Allocate memory to matrix
    A_dense = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*k*sizeof( double ), 128);  // Fails here.
    if (A_dense == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Can't allocate memory for matrices. Aborting... \n\n");
        mkl_free(A_dense);
        return 1;
    }

    mkl_free(A_dense);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
 $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel65
 $ gcc -m64 -I/opt/intel/mkl/include -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm test_alloc.c -o test
test
test_alloc.c: In function 'main':
test_alloc.c:13:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

The output I get with valgrind is thus:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./test
==69680== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==69680== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==69680== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==69680== Command: ./test
==69680== 
==69680== Invalid read of size 8
==69680==    at 0x868D1D1: MKL_MALLOC (in /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.5.220/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
==69680==    by 0x4F56B1C: MKL_MALLOC (in /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.5.220/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so)
==69680==    by 0x4006B0: main (in /export/home/myuser/devel/part_distances/lib/test)
==69680==  Address 0xf42400 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==69680== 
==69680== 
==69680== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==69680==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xF42400
==69680==    at 0x868D1D1: MKL_MALLOC (in /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.5.220/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
==69680==    by 0x4F56B1C: MKL_MALLOC (in /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.5.220/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so)
==69680==    by 0x4006B0: main (in /export/home/myuser/devel/part_distances/lib/test)
==69680==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==69680==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==69680==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==69680==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==69680==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==69680== 
==69680== HEAP SUMMARY:
==69680==     in use at exit: 4,603 bytes in 19 blocks
==69680==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 0 frees, 4,603 bytes allocated
==69680== 
==69680== LEAK SUMMARY:
==69680==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==69680==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==69680==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==69680==    still reachable: 4,603 bytes in 19 blocks
==69680==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==69680== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==69680== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==69680== 
==69680== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==69680== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault
```

## Alternatives

I am using Single Dynamic Linking (SDL) because I can't get static linking to work.

Comment: Those "Begin", "Size is" and "Middle" printouts are not in your code ...

Comment: @unwind: Fixed the valgrind output. I had removed the printouts to create a minimal working example.

Comment: The compiler warning makes alarm bells go off in my head. Looks like some kind of 32/64-bit issue. You could try including `mkl.h` instead of the two files you include now and see if that fixes the compile warning. Also double-check that you are using a 64-bit mkl lib and not a 32-bit lib.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks! `mkl.h` fixes things. I am quite certain that I use 64-bit throughout. The library is only available under `/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64`, there is nothing else under `lib/`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck could you make yours an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation suggests including `mkl.h`.

So change:

```
#include "mkl_types.h"
#include "mkl_spblas.h"
```

to

```
#include "mkl.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a scary warning:

```
test_alloc.c:13:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

I assume this is from the code line that does the call to `mkl_malloc()`:

```
A_dense = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*k*sizeof( double ), 128);
```

This implies that you're missing the header, since otherwise there would be no "integer" here.

Also, you should never cast a `void *` like that in C, [as I might have mentioned before on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: "...never cast a `void *`...": Why not? Any read-up on that? I enabled all warnings and with the fix, I don't get any warnings.

Comment: @Unapiedra I added a link.